# Automate & schedule API requests with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to automate and schedule an API request with Rails? I'd like to make a request and save that information into my database, however I'd probably only need it to make a request every few hours for the most up to date info. It's a good amount of data, so I'd like to have it stored as opposed to making a request every time a user visits.

Is there some kind of rake task that I can set up to do this for me on a schedule (or an alternative for what I'm hoping to accomplish)?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just make a request and then cache the results?

Comment: You can also try Cron Jobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [clockwork](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork) or [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gems are made for running scheduled tasks.

If you're hosted on Heroku, you can also use the [Heroku Scheduler add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler) to execute tasks in your Rails app every 10 minutes, every hour or daily.

Answer (score 2):

The Above solutions are good and may suit your needs. There are more sophisticated queuing and scheduling solutions based on Redis that support multiple retries, have monitoring interfaces etc.

I have had good experiences with Resque and https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler

If you can be sure your code is threadsafe there is also Sidekiq https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs

Answer (score 2):

I'd check out [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq). It uses [redis](https://github.com/antirez/redis) and therefore supports retries like [errata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2155313/errata) mentioned.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs